# cstring m_pszdata doesn't match converted char* in UNICODE

Tags: unicode, cjk, cstring

I tested the Unicode conversion with a UNICODE MFC dialog app, where I can input some Chinese in the edit box. After reading in the characters using

> DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_strUnicode)
>   UpdateDate(TRUE)

the `m_pszdata` of `m_strUnicode` shows "e0 65 2d 4e 1f 75 09 67". Then I used the following code to convert it to char*:

> char *psText; psText = new char[dwMinSize]; 
>   WideCharToMultiByte (CP_OEMCP, NULL, m_strUnicode,-1, psText,
>   dwMinSize, NULL, FALSE);

The `psText` contains "ce de d6 d0 c9 fa d3 d0", nothing similar with the `m_pszdata` of m_strUnicode. Would anyone please explain why it is like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ce de d6 d0 c9 fa d3 d0` is `无中生有` in GBK. You sure you're manipulating Unicode?

---

```
CP_OEMCP instructs the API to use the currently set default OEM codepage.
```

So my guess here is that you're on a Chinese PC with GBK as default codepage.

`无中生有` in UTF16LE is `e0 65 2d 4e 1f 75 09 67` so basically you are converting a UTF-16-LE string to GBK.

Comment: I selected Unicode in MFC project setting when starting the project and I did input 无中生有 to test, assuming Chinese characters are in Unicode format. Was I wrong about this?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I tested again using English letters abcdef and it worked as expected. Am I right to say that whatever the string I input, it will be in UTF-16-LE if UNICODE is used, and after the conversion to multibyte, it will be in the default codepage string?